# Problems in the use of plugin sourcerer joomla

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, joomla

I use a combo box that I plug in Joomla
I'am using the pro version of the plugin sourcerer

But I can not render it in the Joomla!

Plugin version sourcerer:4.1.1 pro

joomla version:2.5.14

[Plugin jQuery ComboBox](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo)

[My site](http://www.mixihome.com/en/)

Comment: Please provide code so we can help you

Comment: Have you enabled sourcerer plugin? Have you used sourcerer successfully at any other part of your site ? At which page of your site have you tried to add the combobox code?

Comment: I would also like to point out that the site is quite slow. It would be worth looking into why this is.

Comment: yes plugin sourcerer is enabled,I'm going to put up the login and register

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/NPMfy/